# How to apply validation for alphanumeric ID?

Tags: java

I have to provide validation to an ID field that is in alphanumeric order. `ID` starts with a letter, followed by 7 digits. How do I validate this in Java? Is it possible to achieve using a MySQL database?

For example, `T1234567` should pass validation, and shows a correctly formatted ID field that I'd like to store.

Comment: Simple if statement? Regex? If you can't do this you've already bitten off more than you can chew...

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried in order to do this validation? http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

[Java Pattern library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

You'll want to use this library to do any sort of pattern matching. I'm not sure about the structure of your application, but at its most basic level, this kind of validation based on a pattern should be done using regular expressions (regex). Feel free to do some research on the topic if you're not familiar with it.

The pattern you described would be captured by the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z|a-z]\\d{7}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(someID);
boolean validId = m.matches();
```

There are many ways to do this however.